# how to change the directory to save uploaded files in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, file-upload, assets

I'm using angular 2 and i have an uploader. the default folder to save the file is in `/assets` folder. is there any way to change this directory to a file server for example?
this is my .ts code:

```
    uploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader({
    url: '/upload/uploadUserImage',
    isHTML5: true
  });
```

and this is my .js file in backend:

```
 const storageUserImage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './src/assets/uploads/profile_images/');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  }
});

const uploadUserImage = multer({
  storage: storageUserImage
}).single('file');
////////////
  module.exports = (router) => {
  router.post('/uploadUserImage', function (req, res) {
    uploadUserImage(req, res, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        res.json({
          error_code: 1,
          err_desc: err
        });
        return;
      }
      res.json({
        error_code: 0,
        err_desc: null
      });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes according to multer documentation you have destination function in which you may define your path that where it should be stored.

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, '/../../tmp/my-uploads') // source folder
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
  }
})
```